# Get value of the checkbox created by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I wanna get the value of some checkboxes that is in my page, but the problem it is that this checkboxes are created by ajax, and how the javascript is executed before the my ajax mount my checkboxes, the function that gets the value of this element is null.

The code is like this:

```
function salvar()
{  

 //here is the problem, because this inputs is not here, 
 //I have a ajax function that creates this inputs
 var checkBoxes = $('input[name=checkbox]');

 var idsTelas;
 var i = 0;

 $.each(checkBoxes, function()
 {
       if ($(this).attr('checked'))
       {
           idsTelas[i] = $(this).val();
           i++;
       }
 });
}
```

Comment: How about posting some code showing what you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but 1) http://whathaveyoutried.com 2) http://stackoverflow.com/faq - read those to be able to ask better questions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you saw, but I'm new here, and I'm learning how to post in this site including my english, that I have difficulties yet. I think that you may tell me how the best form to post here before downvote in my question.

Comment: @Lennon - don't take the downvote personally, it's a measure of whether the question is well-written or not - nothing to do with whether you're worthy of help!

Comment: sorry it, but wasn't this that I wanted to say, it's that I'm learning yet, thank you by the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are going about this the wrong way:

> I wanna get the value of some checkboxes that is in my page, but the problem it is that this checkboxes are created by ajax, and how **the javascript is executed before the my ajax mount my checkboxes**

If I understand you correctly, your Javascript is executing before the checkboxes are created/inserted into the page.

So - when the Javascript runs, you want to get the value of things that don't exist yet?  That is quite simply not going to be possible, regardless of any clever tricks.

The only way to resolve this is to change the relative timings.  You'll need to run your `salvar()` function *after* the checkboxes have been created by AJAX.  Or alternatively, if you can't push back execution of the function for some reason, you'll need to bring the AJAX creation step forwards.  Either way, there *has* to be a dependency between creating the checkboxes and *then* invoking `salvar()`.

Comment: It's like this, on the document's onLoad() is executed the AJAX to load my checkboxes, and in the page already have a button that call the salvar() function, so when the page is ready, the checkboxes already are loaded and after I click on the button to execute the salvar(). I only run this function after the AJAX have been invoked.